# ¿Cómo cambiar formato de input type=date?

Tags: html, css, css3, date, input

Necesito que el i'nput type=date' al momento de escoger la fecha se muestre de la siguiente forma:

```
             Hoy, 02 Febrero 2020
             Miercoles,30 Febrero 2020
```

Y no de la forma tradicional '08/02/2020', he pasado mucho tiempo buscando pero aun no encuentro solución.

Comment: Puede darle un vistazo a esta pagina https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.date.php  ahí explica los parámetros para el formato de las fechas

Comment: El formato de fecha se muestra de acuerdo al navegador, tienes que cambiar estilos y usar librerias externas, aqui hay varios [ejemplos](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/date-picker/)

Comment: En si los input tipo date no tienen formato. Se tiene que hacer mediante Css y JavaScript. Es necesario que se muestre en el formato que mencionas?

Answer (score 1):

### Formatear fechas

> Lamentablemente, al consultar en [***whatwg.org*** la lista de atributos disponibles](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) para el elemento `input` no encontré ninguno que tuviera que ver con formatos de fecha.
>
> Sin embargo, te presentaré una alternativa que podrás utilizar para presentarle al usuario un formato de fecha legible.

Para conseguir un formato de fecha legible al usuario tomaremos en cuenta algunos detalles:

- Definir unas reglas CSS para ocultar el campo de fecha que estará dentro del elemento `label`.
- Presentar con la etiqueta `label` el formato de fecha legible al usuario. Sin embargo, el formato `YYYY-MM-DD` se mantendrá.

**El código HTML a definir será:**

```html
<label for="fecha" class="etiqueta">
  <span id="textFecha">Seleccione una fecha</span>
  <input type="date" id="fecha" class="fecha" />
</label>
```

Mientras que definiremos los siguientes estilos para ocultar el campo de fecha y mostrar un ***formato de fecha legible*** al usuario:

```css
.fecha {
  /* Ocultar el campo de fecha */
  display: none;
}

/* Asignarle una apariencia a label */
.etiqueta {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 10px;

  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.etiqueta:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Y los más importante se encuentra en el siguiente fragmento de código:

```js
fecha.onchange = () => {
  // Opciones de formato de fecha, con
  // traducción al español:
  const opciones = {
    weekday: "long", // diadelasemana: 'largo'
    year: "numeric", // año: 'numérico'
    month: "long",   // mes: 'largo'
    day: "numeric",  // día: 'numérico'
    timeZone: "UTC"  // zonaHoraria: 'UTC'
  };

  let
    // Instanciando el objeto Date con la
    // fecha seleccionada por el usuario:
    vFecha = new Date(fecha.value),
    
    // Almacenar la fecha formateada para mostrarla posteriormente al usuario:
    fechaFormateada = vFecha.toLocaleDateString("es-VE", opciones);

  // Mostrar la fecha seleccionada al usuario:
  textFecha.textContent = fechaFormateada;
};
```

Con el método `toLocateDateString()` estableceremos el idioma y formato de la fecha. Es decir, `vFecha.toLocateDateString( 'es-VE', opciones )`. Donde `es-VE` es el idioma español Venezuela y `opciones` el objeto en el que se encuentra definido el formato de la fecha.

#### Probando código

Ya entendida la explicación en esta publicación ejecutemos las pruebas en el siguiente fragmento de código:

```js
fecha.onchange = () => {
  // Opciones de formato de fecha:
  const opciones = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    timeZone: 'UTC'
  };

  let
    // Instanciando el objeto Date con la
    // fecha seleccionada por el usuario:
    vFecha = new Date( fecha.value ),

    // Almacenar la fecha formateada para mostrarla posteriormente al usuario:
    fechaFormateada = vFecha.toLocaleDateString( 'es-VE', opciones );

  // Mostrar la fecha seleccionada al usuario:
  textFecha.textContent = fechaFormateada;
}
```

```css
.fecha {
  display: none;
}

.etiqueta {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 10px;

  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.etiqueta:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

```html
<label for="fecha" class="etiqueta">
  <span id="textFecha">Seleccione una fecha</span>
  <input type="date" id="fecha" class="fecha">
</label>
```

Se pudo observar que presenta la fecha en un formato legible para el usuario.

> **IMPORTANTE:**
>
> Recuerde que para establecer un formato de fecha en función de un idioma y país debes definirlas así: `idioma-PAIS`, es decir, `es-VE`; donde `es` es el idioma español y `VE` es el código del país; en este caso, Venezuela.
>
> Puede consultar el sitio Web de la [*Organización Internacional para la Estandarización*](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/es/#search) (ISO, por sus siglas en inglés).
>
> **Nota:**
>
> Si ingresa al sitio Web de la ISO, asegúrese de elegir un idioma en el buscador y presione «SEARCH» y a la izquierda de la página busque un texto que diga algo parecido a «Códigos de país» y le das clic.

Puede consultar [Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Answer (score 0):

Hola quizas mi respuesta pueda ser desalentadora pero no puedes cambiar el formato que se encuentra en el unpit de tipo date.

Hay una diferencia entre lo que es el formato sobre la pantalla y el formato de presentacion del navegador, ambas son cosas distintas y tu lo que quieres cambiar es el formato de presentacion. Lo que tienes en el html ya esta definido y a menos de que el propio html te de la opcion para cambiar dicho parametro no es posible hacerlo directo desde html, es como querer cambiar directamente sobre un h1 su tamaño de letra, a pesar de que podrias agregar una etiqueta style esto ya es parte de CSS y no como tal de HTML.

Ahora bien, los navegadores como tal no tienen ningun tipo de restriccion con respecto a como se presenta una entrada de fecha, es mas incluso en los navegadores de moviles estos cambian de acuerdo al idioma con el que este configurado el dispositivo en algunos casos y puede que en lugar de aparecer un formato YYYY-MM-DD pueda aparecer algo como DD-MM-YYYY.

Como resumen te puedo decir que puedes configurar todo esto pero tiene que ser de forma manual utilizando javascript y dandole otro formato de presentacion pero el navegador no puede darte esas opciones. Tu deberas de terminar controlando el formato de fecha que recives, como lo recibes y en donde lo recibes y de igual forma si se presenta algun error de compatibilidad con tus formatos de fecha todo ya corre por tu cuenta asi que pon mucha atencion cuando lo vayas a intentar.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo tan simple como efectivo para modificar el formato de la fecha. Posteriormente tendrás que pasárselo al campo donde quieras que figure:

```js
var d = new Date();

       var day = new Array(6);
       day [0] = "Domingo";
       day [1] = "Lunes";
       day [2] = "Martes";
       day [3] = "Miércoles";
       day [4] = "Jueves";
       day [5] = "Viernes";
       day [6] = "Sábado";

        var month = new Array(11);
        month[0] = "Enero";
        month[1] = "Febrero";
        month[2] = "Marzo";
        month[3] = "Abril";
        month[4] = "Mayo";
        month[5] = "Junio";
        month[6] = "Julio";
        month[7] = "Agosto";
        month[8] = "Septiembre";
        month[9] = "Octubre";
        month[10] = "Noviembre";
        month[11] = "Diciembre";

        document.write('<div style="padding: 15px; background: #000;color:#fff; text-align:center; font-weight: bold">Hoy&nbsp;es&nbsp;' + day[d.getDay()] + ',&nbsp;' + d.getDate() + '&nbsp;de&nbsp;' + month[d.getMonth()] + "&nbsp;de&nbsp;" + d.getFullYear() + '</div>');
```